# Javascript dataTable - Adding link to table

Tags: javascript, datatable

I am using javascript dataTable and I'm populating a table by getting the data via an api link this:

```
jQuery.get(api_url_here", function(dataSet){

    jQuery('#myTable').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { "data": "id", "title": "theId" },
            { "data": "name", "title": "theName" }
        ]
    });


});

<table id="myTable" class="display"></table>
```

This all works as required but I need one of the columns to have a link created so that when the user clicks the id it will go to the url assigned with the id...

For example:  `<a href="someurl+{id}">theId</a>`

How can I do this with dataTable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"ajax": "./pasien/look/",
aoColumns: [
  { "mData": null }
],
columnDefs: [{
  "targets": 0,
  "data": null,
  "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
  return '<a href="#">'+ row.mr +'</a>';
 }
}]
```

try this, i use ajax for data in datatables.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
            {
                "data": "id",
                "title": "theId",
                "aTargets": [0],
                "sType": "numeric"
            },
            {
                "className":        '',
                "orderable":        false,
                "data":             null,
                "defaultContent":   '<a href="your link"</a>'
            }];
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a event thats fired when the cell is created, you can then write normal javascript to set it's content with the id:

```
jQuery.get("api_url_here", function(dataSet){
    jQuery('#myTable').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { "data": "id", "title": "theId",
                "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                    $(nTd).html("<a class='display' href='" + oData.id + "'>" + oData.id + "</a>");
                }
            },
            { "data": "name", "title": "theName" }
        ]
    });
});
```

I hope it helps you.

I took the answer from https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/25111/hyperlink-in-td.